# How to update product position of a product in a specific category of specific store view in magento 2.4.4

Tags: multistore, category-products, magento2.4.4, position

I have a multi-store website and have more than 30 categories. I have a requirement like updating the product **position**.

For example, I have a category 'XYZ' which contains more than 500+ products available. this category is enabled for default scope and other store view scopes such as 'A', 'B', and 'C'(I'm taking A, B, and C as an example of different store views).

So I want to update the product **position** of every product in the 'XYZ' category only for the 'B' store view (while updating, other store view product positions should not be changed).

I have tried using the `repository/category` model object to update the product **position** for a specific store view, but it takes so long if we are updating almost 100 products.

I also tried `setProductsPosition($productPosition)` method to update the product, but this is updating the product **position** for all the store views.

Does anyone have any idea how to update the product **position** only for a specific category of a specific store view?

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Get the product object by SKU 
$product = $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
    
    // Check if the product exists if ($product) {
        // Define the position
        $position = your_new_position;
    
        // Define the category ID
        $categoryId = your_category_id;
    
        // Get the product's existing category IDs
        $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
    
        // Check if the category is already assigned to the product
        if (in_array($categoryId, $categoryIds)) {
            // Update the product's position in the category for a specific store
            $product->setStoreId(your_store_id)->setCategoryIds([$categoryId => $position])->save();
            echo "Product position updated successfully.";
        } else {
            echo "Product is not assigned to the specified category.";
        } } else {
        echo "Product not found."; }
```

This approach ensures that you update the product position for a specific category and store view correctly within Magento's data structure.

Comment: In catalog_category_product table, there is no column for store id

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Thank you for your response and effort on this. I have checked the database and we can't add product position category-wise for different store views as the Magento architecture goes that way only.